# Amazon Pinpoint - send a scheduled message to a specific user

Tags: amazon-web-services, push-notification, aws-pinpoint

I am using Amazon Pinpoint to send push notification to my users' devices and I'm looking for a way to send a message to a specific user/device at a specified time (e.g. 15 minutes from now).  Is there a way to accomplish this using Pinpoint?

Comment: Did you find a way to perform this? I am exactly looking for the proper way to achieve this... Everything I have found so far implies using a dinamoDB for storing the notification scheduling info.

Comment: @mcartur It was a long time ago, so things may have changed and I don't exactly remember, but I believe we had to build this ability into our application.  We didn't find a way to do it in Pinpoint.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, that is possible with Amazon Pinpoint. Please see documentation regarding setting up and executing a scheduled campaign. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/userguide/campaigns.html

thanks

Comment: We tried this but it didn't suit our needs because we had to create a new campaign and segment for each notification we wanted to send out.